# how to merge several data frames with similar columns and avoid duplicate data by setting priority for the data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

priority is as follows df1>df2>df3, so if the data is in df1 and df2, only df1 is selected etc

df1:

1. A123
2. A223
3. A323
4. A313
5. A311
6. A111

df2:

1. A123
2. A223
3. A323
4. A456
5. A234
6. A212

df3:

1. A999
2. A876
3. A657
4. A897

output:

1. A123
2. A223
3. A323
4. A313
5. A311
6. A111
7. A456
8. A234
9. A212
10. A999
11. A876
12. A657
13. A897

Answer (score 0):

You first append by the priority order and then remove duplicates choosing to keep the first occurance:

```
df = df1.append(df2)
df = df.append(df3)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[column name], keep = first)
```

Comment: You can chain this like `df1.append(df2).append(df3)`.